# I need to have a key with multiple values. What datastructure would you recommend?

Tags: c++, data-structures, key

I have an string array filled with words from a sentence.

```
words[0] = "the"
words[1] = "dog"
words[2] = "jumped"
words[3] = "over"
words[4] = "the"
words[5] = "wall."
words[6] = "the"
words[7] = "cat"
words[8] = "fell"
words[9] = "off"
words[10] = "the"
words[10] = "house."
```

etc.
(Stupid example, but it works for this)

Each word will be a key with it's following word as it's value. so "over" => "the". Some keys can have multiple values. For example, "the" => "dog" || "wall" || "cat" || "house". The value is randomly chosen from those for that key.

When the program runs it picks a word at random and makes a sentence. So it could be something like: "the cat fell off the dog".

I tried implementing a map (map myMap;) but this allows only one value per key (I think).

Hope I explained this right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use a multimap from the STL and use the call

```
pair<iterator, iterator> equal_range(const key_type& k)
```

to get a range of iterators that match your key

personally i find this slightly clunky due to having to deal with iterator ranges rather than just getting an object back that represents all values for that key.  to get around that you could also store a vector in a regular map and add your strings to the vector.

Answer (score 42):

[`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

The link provides an excellent example. Quoted below:

```
 int main()
{
  multimap<const char*, int, ltstr> m;

  m.insert(pair<const char* const, int>("a", 1));
  m.insert(pair<const char* const, int>("c", 2));
  m.insert(pair<const char* const, int>("b", 3));
  m.insert(pair<const char* const, int>("b", 4));
  m.insert(pair<const char* const, int>("a", 5));
  m.insert(pair<const char* const, int>("b", 6));

  cout << "Number of elements with key a: " << m.count("a") << endl;
  cout << "Number of elements with key b: " << m.count("b") << endl;
  cout << "Number of elements with key c: " << m.count("c") << endl;

  cout << "Elements in m: " << endl;
  for (multimap<const char*, int, ltstr>::iterator it = m.begin();
       it != m.end();
       ++it)
   cout << "  [" << (*it).first << ", " << (*it).second << "]" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When using a map I can access the values by using map[key]. How can I get the values using a multimap?

Comment: @Haawk: multimap has an method called equal_range() that will return a pair of iterators indicating the range of elements equal to a given key.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using C++ then just create a class to represent your key-value pairs:

```
Class foo {
    key : String
    values : list of values
}
```

Then, create a map that maps each key to an object containing its values.

This is simple, extendable, and can be done in any OO-language.

Sorry, my C++ is rusty so the syntax is wrong, but the essential idea is straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that a struct may work well for this situation.  This approach (basically akin to a class) allows a cleaner access to your parameters named as you see fit.

```
struct car_parts {

    string wheelType;
    string engine;
    int number_of_cylinders;

    car_parts(string _wheelType, string _engine, int _number_of_cylinders)
    {
        wheelType = _wheelType;
        engine = _engine;
        number_of_cylinders = _number_of_cylinders;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Populate the dictionary
    map<char, car_parts> vehicles =
    {
        { 'I', car_parts("All terrain", "X2", 6) },
        { 'C', car_parts("Summer only", "BB", 8) },
        { 'U', car_parts("All terrain", "X3", 4) }
    };

    map<char, car_parts>::iterator it;

    it = vehicles.find('I');

    if (it != vehicles.end())
    {
        cout << "The vehicle with key of I has " << it->second.number_of_cylinders << " cylinders\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As two others pointed out, `std::multimap` can be your solution.

Also consider [std::tr1::unordered_multimap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982291.aspx). It is available in `VS 2008` seems to have it, `GCC` has it at least from version `4.3`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `unordered_map<char,vector<string>>` which has some benefit over map structure. You can do such insertion if your dictionary is like `'c': "cat"`, `'c':"car"`, `'a':apple`, `'a':"angus"` :

```
unordered_map<char, vector<string>> char_to_strings_map;
//loop to traverse the dictionary : key:c, value:s
  char_to_strings_map[c].emplace_back(s);
//loop ends
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be an alternate approach to achieve two values per key, especially  for the cases when most of the map elements have two values per key. By pairing two values for a key, as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560573/stdmap-one-key-two-values):

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::int, int> > myMap2
```

use it in the function as:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
int main(){
map<string,pair<int,int>>mp;
mp.insert(pair<string,pair<int,int>>("ab",make_pair(50,7)));
mp.insert(pair<string,pair<int,int>>("cd",make_pair(51,8)));
map<string,pair<int,int>>::iterator it;
for(it=mp.begin();it!=mp.end();it++)
    cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second.first<<" "<<it->second.second<<" ";
return 0;
}
```