# std::map one key, two values

Tags: c++, stl

What is the best way to map two values to one key?

ie An item with a value and bool.

Tried using:

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, bool> > myMap2
```

But that doesn't seem like the correct solution.  Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: `std::pair<>` is just fine. What is your concern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is indeed the correct solution. More generally, consider using `std::tuple` instead of `std::pair` for a uniform interface regardless of the number of values (as `std::pair` is obviously restricted to two), or [`boost::tuple`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) if your compiler is too old to ship with a `std::` or `std::tr1::` implementation.

Comment: @Steve: ...which will be when the tuple contains more than two items.  :)  Seriously, tuples promote unreadable code when their contents are not homogenously typed or structured in some obvious way.  Code that says `iter->second.get<6>()` is nasty.

Comment: @John: arguably even when it contains more than *one* item :-). I think what you can get away with depends a bit on how widely the tuple is used. In a small area of code it's not so bad, in a widely-used public interface stuff should probably be named. For example I'd prefer it if the members of map elements were named `key`, `value` rather than `first`, `second`, but `std::pair` already exists, it comes with `make_pair`, so it's probably worth putting up with that to avoid a second near-identical class template `map_entry<Key,Value>`.

Answer (score 6):

Either use `std::pair<>` as you did, or make a custom struct containing the values you want to store.  I'd do the latter in most cases, as the values then have names more descriptive than `first` and `second`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I crate a simple mapValue struct/class.