# In multimap, how to get the key associated to a given value?

Tags: c++, c++11, multimap

I have my `multimap<int, std::string> map`, which represents a prioritisation of some values, like this (in descending order of priority):

```
<1, "element1"> // max priority
<1, "element2">
<1, "element3">
<2, "element4">
<3, "element5">
<3, "element6"> // min priority
```

Is there a way, given a value string "elementx", to determine to what key (thus priority) it is associated?

Comment: What if there is more than one key for a given value?

Comment: For how my code is set, it shouldn't happen: every element has one and one only priority.

Comment: Then why not just use a `std::map`?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what I read on the documentation!
Then I will use `std::map`.
But this question might be useful to someone, should I delete it anyway?

Comment: @elmazzun `std::map` won't work for you, because it only allows one value per key, and you have one or more values per key.

Comment: Then why `std::multimap` is not suited for my purpose?
I read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698345/i-need-to-have-a-key-with-multiple-values-what-datastructure-would-you-recommen and since `std::map` allows a single association <key,value>, I thought that `std::multimap` was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to have a reverse map `<string, int> map` when you are building your map (to search faster) or just go through your map by an iterator:

```
for (auto it:map)
{
    if (it.second == "elementx")
    {
         std::cout << it.first << std:endl;
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remember that 'auto it:map' copies by value... You probably want `auto& it:map` to avoid copying those strings...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search a `std::map` by value.

Your only option is to iterate over the entire map and compare the values of each item in the map with `"elementx"`. You can gather the keys in a suitable container, such as a `std::set`.